# Expose Content of a Discriminated Union Case

Tags: f#

I am wondering if there is a good way of exposing the content of a DU case to the DU type itself.

For example:

```
[<Measure>] type inch

module StructuralShape =

    type Plate =
        {
        Length : float<inch>
        Thickness : float<inch>
        }

    type SingleAngle =
        {
        VerticalLeg : float<inch>
        HorizontalLeg : float<inch>
        Thickness : float<inch>
        }

    type StructuralShape =
        | Plate of Plate
        | SingleAngle of SingleAngle

    let area (ss : StructuralShape) =
        match ss with
        | Plate pl -> pl.Length * pl.Thickness
        | SingleAngle sa -> 
            (sa.HorizontalLeg + sa.VerticalLeg - sa.Thickness) * sa.Thickness

    type StructuralShape with
        member ss.Area = area ss

module Test =
    open StructuralShape

    let myShape = Plate {Length = 2.0<inch>; Thickness = 0.25<inch>}
    let area = myShape.Area

    // Looking to allow the user of the library
    // to access the internal shape properties
    // without having to use some type of 'get shape' function

    let length = myShape.Length  // fails
```

After a re-look at my design, which was inconsistent as Fyodor pointed out, I decided to create an interface for IShape.

```
[<Measure>] type inch
type IShape = interface end

module StructuralShapes = 

    type Plate =
        {
        Length : float<inch>
        Thickness : float<inch>
        }
        interface IShape

    type SingleAngle =
        {
        VerticalLeg : float<inch>
        HorizontalLeg : float<inch>
        Thickness : float<inch>
        }
        interface IShape

    let area (shape: IShape) =
        match shape with
        | :? Plate as pl -> pl.Length * pl.Thickness
        | :? SingleAngle as sa ->
            (sa.HorizontalLeg + sa.VerticalLeg - sa.Thickness)
             * sa.Thickness
        | _ -> failwith "Shape not suppported."

    type IShape with
        member this.Area = area this
```

Note: For simplicity, this is a simplified version of the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to achieve here. I suspect you may have inconsistent design in your mind and not realize it.

If your `StructuralShape` type only ever has one case, then why do you need it at all? Just use `Plate` instead!

If your `StructuralShape` type will have more cases, then what happens when the actual value doesn't have a `Thickness` field?

If your `StructuralShape` type will have more cases, but all of them are required to have a `Thickness` field, and that field has the same type *and the same meaning* for all of them, then a better design would be to "lift" the common fields to the common type, and leave only differences under the DU:

```
type Plate = { Length: float }
type Foo = { Bar: string }

type StructuralShapeInfo = Plate of Plate | Foo of Foo

type StructuralShape = { Info: StructuralShapeInfo; Thickness: float }
```

(pardon my choice of `Info` suffix; I realize it's not the best choice, but I can't come up with a better one without knowing your domain and thinking about it for a while; there are three hard problems in programming: naming stuff and off-by-one errors)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for not being clear. I have adjusted by question to add an extra case, and have emphasized that I will be looking to get a field of a case which is not required by every case in the DU. I think that your answer sheds light on some issue, but may not be exactly what I am looking for (my fault for not being clear). If you wouldn't mind taking a look and letting me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Sooo... In your updated code, what do you want to happen when `myShape` is `SingleAngle`, which doesn't have the `Length`?

Comment: I guess I was hoping that there would be a way of accessing the internals of the 'SingleAngle' type and therefore the '.' accessor would only give myShape.VerticalLeg, myShape.HorizontalLeg, etc. If this isn't possible then I suppose I could have a type StructuralShape<'T> = {Shape :'T; StructuralShapeInfo : StructuralShapeInfo}.

Comment: But you haven't answered the question: what did you expect to happen when you do `myShape.Length`, and `myShape` doesn't have a `Length` field? What should happen in that case?

Comment: I suppose it could return None. In which case I might be able to use an option type.

Comment: In that case, @thequickbrownfox's answer is the way to go. And no, there is no built-in language support for it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can augment a discriminated union with members, which is useful for convenient access in cases like this:

```
type StructuralShape =
    | Plate of Plate
    member this.Thickness = match this with Plate p -> p.Thickness
```

If you add any new cases to `StructuralShape`, then you need to handle the case in the code for this property.

This may be a useful thing to know, but Fyodor makes a very good point in his answer about reorganising your data model so this isn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have adjusted by question to add an extra case, and have emphasized that I will be looking to get a field of a case which is not required by every case in the DU. With that said, I think your answer may work if I use an option. I.e. ... -> Some p.Thickness

Comment: This actually does a good job of mimicking what I am trying to bring to code: https://www.aisc.org/globalassets/product-files-not-searched/manuals/aiscshapesdatabasev14_1-current.zip . If you open that you will see that each shape has properties that are either 'Some Value' or None. But as you may imagine, this would get real clumsy.